# angularjs ngTable "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular'" with webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular'` after adding `ng-table.js` to my angular module.

The error is referring to this part in `ng-table.js`

```
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['angular'], function(angular) {
            return factory(angular);
        });
    } else {
        return factory(angular);
    }
```

my webpack/angular looks something like this

```
    'use strict';
    import './../bower/angular/angular.min.js';
    import './../bower/ng-table/dist/ng-table.js';
    window.app = angular.module('appName',["ngRoute", "ngTable"]);
    // routes
    app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'home',
                templateUrl: 'partials/views/home.html',
                activeClass: 'home'
            })
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl:'partials/views/404.html'
            }); 
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
    require('./ng-controller.js');
```

Do you know why I need to require('angular') or how to fix this?

Comment: u can see what i have in my app.js above... I think im doing it correct. (the other modules work)

Comment: https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/764#issuecomment-184357333

Comment: im using angularjs... is this even for ng1?

Comment: did you solve this problem ?